# Yii2 how to send controller action response without redirect?

Tags: ajax, yii2, single-page-application, renderpartial

I have a Single page application in Yii2

the main page contains 
1. a column with a list of objects + create button
2. a column for dynamic content of create/update forms

My problem is when loading (through ajax) a create form, and then I am sending data through AjaxSubmitButton which woks fine (db updated) but instead of changing the dynamic content area with the new object data it redirects to a view partial form.

How can I make the new response go into the same div that it is being sent from?

this is the form that is loaded now in #singleObjContainer

```
    <div class="course-form">

<?php 
    $form = yii\bootstrap\ActiveForm::begin(); 
?>

<span>
    <h4 class='listTitle'>Add Course</h4> 
</span>
<span class="form-group pull-right">
    <?php 

        AjaxSubmitButton::begin([
            'label' => 'Save',
            'ajaxOptions' => [
                'type'=>'POST',
                'url'=> Url::toRoute(['course/create-form']),
                'success' => new \yii\web\JsExpression('function(html)
                {
                    $("#singleObjContainer").empty().append(html);
                }'),
            ],
            'options' => ['class' => 'btn btn-success', 'type' => 'submit'],
            ]);

        AjaxSubmitButton::end();
    ?>
</span>

<hr class='myHr'>

<div>
<?php

    echo $form->field($model, 'name')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]);

    echo $form->field($model, 'description')->textarea(['rows' => '4']);

    echo $form->field($model, 'img')->label(Html::img(Yii::getAlias('@uploadsUrl/').'courses/'.$model->img,['width' => '30%']),['encodeLabel' => false])->fileInput();

?>
</div>

<?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

and this is the controller action:

```
    public function actionCreateForm()
{
    $model = new Course();


    if ( $model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) 
    {
        // get the instance of the image
        $image = UploadedFile::getInstance( $model, 'img');

        // save image name to the model
        $model->img = $image->baseName.".".$image->extension;

        // go through validation rule and save
        if( $model->save() )
        {
            // validation ok, save image in the file system
            $image->saveAs( Yii::getAlias('@uploads/').'courses/'.$model->img);

            // load the details view into the singleObj container

            $courseStudents = $this->getCourseStudents($model['id']);

            return $this->renderPartial('_viewForm', ['model' => $model, 'courseStudents' => $courseStudents]);


        }
    }
    else 
    {
        return $this->renderPartial('_createForm', ['model' => $model,]);
    }


}
```

Comment: instead of using `renderPartial` use `renderAjax`

Answer (score 0):

If you need that your result is send directly to the ajax request .. just return  .. eventually using a json_encode for the array.

```
  return json_encode( $model);
```

this way you obtain a json answer with struct equivalent to your $model

In  your controller add  a proper action

```
public function actionRefreshForm()
{
  //your appllication code 
   $my_new_html_code ='<div>test new html code </div>;
   return $my_new_html_code;

}
```

In your ajaxOptions call the related  action

```
 'ajaxOptions' => [
            'type'=>'POST',
            'url'=> Url::toRoute(['course/refresh-form']),
            'success' => new \yii\web\JsExpression('function(html)
            {
                $("#singleObjContainer").empty().append(html);
            }'),
        ],
```

Comment: The response is ok. The problem is that it redirects the page and I want it to stay in the original page and update response content in the specified div

Comment: explain better your comment ..  what do you mean?

Comment: The problem is that it redirects the page and I want it to stay in the original page and update response content in the specified div

Comment: You are calling the same controller/action for show the page and for update the html .  ???  if don't want the redirects / refesh  .. the you should separate the action for render  the html update ...use a different controller(action .. one for create the page  ... another for send  the new html

Comment: can you give a imple example of how to do that??

Answer (score 0):

You can use `yii\widgets\Pjax`. It will be easy for you I guess. You can learn more about it in this article. [http://blog.neattutorials.com/yii2-pjax-tutorial](http://blog.neattutorials.com/yii2-pjax-tutorial/).